# How to solve error of "Middlechild" package installation

Tags: r

I had an issue when installing the middlechild package. The error information are:

```
##Rd warning:` ##C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcdCCZ4/R.INSTALL293c41927138/middlechild/man/call_mitm.Rd:10: file link 'exec_background' in package 'sys' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
##Rd warning: C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcdCCZ4/R.INSTALL293c41927138/middlechild/man/pipe.Rd:10: file link '%>%' in package 'magrittr' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
##Rd warning:` ##C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcdCCZ4/R.INSTALL293c41927138/middlechild/man/start_mitm.Rd:15: file link 'exec_background' in package 'sys' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
```

These errors prevent me getting the package into library. They look as:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘middlechild’: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'middlechild', details: call: find_mitm()  error: mitmdump not found. Please run middlechild::install_mitm().
```

Does anyone have experience/answers to help me out of this issue?

Comment: check https://github.com/ropenscilabs/middlechild/blob/master/man/install_mitm.Rd and run install_mitm()

Comment: Thanks! But I am too new on R to understand what it is saying, could you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**; install [mitmproxy](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/)

Okay. Following your reply to my comment and because i would love for you to be the best programmer you can become faster, i will take some time to help you acquire something that is crucial and for which you will inevitably thank me for for the rest of your life - and beyond.

First, programing languages usually use parenthesis at the end of one or a collection of words to define a `function()`.

When coding and creating your own functions, naming them in a short and meaningful way (explicit to it's function), will greatly help both identifying what it does quickly and reduce the amount of typing you do each time you call it. It will also help others understand the overall program faster and sometimes better which in term increases your chances of reviews/collaboration etc...

Never cheap out on adding meaningful comments to your functions in order to quickly be able to graphically visualize a process, method or train of thought which justified creating such a function. It willl not only help others get a firm grasp on your code/ideas but will also more than likely act as narration to the process making it easier to understand.

**Now**... in the current context...

```
Error:
package or namespace load failed for ‘middlechild’:
    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'middlechild', details:
        call: find_mitm()
        error: mitmdump not found. Please run middlechild::install_mitm().
```

This error should let you know, fairly explicitly too, what has happenned and if you are lucky, this will also allow you to quickly find a solution for the current problem.

When running the function `loadNamespace()`, another function was executed. It has a very fitting name too, `.onload()`.

This `onload()` function, at least to me very logically, looks just like a initialization step from which the environment/dependencies are verified/loaded to ensure a worry-free execution. We can now fairly conclude, from the rest of the error message, that unfortunately for us, **mitmdump** is a requirement that is not met.

`onload()` function asked/called another function, again with a very fitting name, to **find *mitm*** as **mitmdump** is needed to proceed. `find_mitm()` is one friendly function which steers us in the right direction, even after such a failure.... It tells us to make sure we have ran the function `install_mitm()` which to me anyways, and your guess is as good as mine, does somethings in order to install `mitm` which should provide the needed **mitmdump**.

A quick web search for function [install_mitm()](https://github.com/ropenscilabs/middlechild/blob/master/man/install_mitm.Rd) helps us *quickly understand, after a very short read* that we need to install [mitmproxy](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/).

So briefly (hahahhaha), try and be logical about the information that is presented to you and do not be affraid of trying stuff and opening multiple browser tabs. The availability of tools to solve your problems would mean that even if you try very minimally, you should get further than where you sit now with the help of a single "i'm feeling lucky" search.

Wow. thats alot of words. beer time.

[image: mitmproxy install page telling us about standalone binaries on mitmproxy.org]

Comment: OMG, thank for the great patience and help! I have installed the mitmproxy package to my Windows 10, but it didn't work. It seems I have to install the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). Trying it out.

Comment: Oh Yeah! I got it finally. Thx again for your help!

Comment: Pleasure, thanks for posting your findings and outcome